# Out of Memory when Switching Activities

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm making an android app with a menu activity and a game activity. Switching from the menu to the game and then back to the menu works, but as soon as you try to go back to the game activity, I get an out of memory error. The game activity loads in a few bitmaps, so in the onStop() method for the game activity I tried recycling all the bitmaps, calling finish(),and calling gc(), but none of it worked, I still get the out of memory error when I try to switch back to the game activity. I've tried researching this but so far I haven't found anything that helps. Is there any way to fix this and ensure my game activity is completely released from memory when it is closed?

Comment: some code would help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OutOfMemory error occurs when your application did not get enough memory to proceed for object allocation.  Check with the memory size given to the application  since you are using bitmap memory consumption might be more. Please increase the memory limit and check the behavior.